# Switch case or different URL? what should I use in Springboot controller for calling different services

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am developing Spring boot application in which I have different services responding single request. I am identifying services which serve request by getting serviceId from the request.

Right now I am using Switch case to identify the request type and calls service accordingly.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/app")
public class ApiController{
    @Autowired
    Service service;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/service", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = { "application/json" })
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseModel> processAPIRequest(@RequestBody ApiRequest req){
        String serviceId = req.getServiceId();
        ResponseModel resp = new ResponseModel();
        switch (serviceId.trim()) {
            case "SER0001":
                resp = service.getDetails01(req);
                break;              
            case "SER0002":
                resp = service.getDetails03(req);
                break;




            case "SER0030":
                resp = service.getDetails30(req);
                break;
        return resp;
    }
}
```

In Above what should I use for better performance? A switch case statement or create new Method which serve each request by adding serviceId in url? e.g.`@RequestMapping(value = "/service/serviceId", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = { "application/json" })`

Comment: how about fetching this information from database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, controller method must not contain logic. You must create single method `Service#getDetails`.

Secondly, I would recommend you do this (returns HTTP 200 for example):

```
@PostMapping(value = "/service/{serviceId}")
public ResponseEntity<ResponseModel> processAPIRequest(@PathVariable int serviceId, @RequestBody ApiRequest req) {

    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(service.getDetails(serviceId, req));
}
```

I would also like to say that if you are forced to use a mile-long `switch`, then something is wrong with the architecture of your application.

Comment: does Switch-catch consumes more time than individual request method?